# Chromatic number of a graph if it is a union of two subgraphs having null or single point intersection

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Consider two edge disjoint graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ having the null graph on $k$ vertices as their intersection, where $k$ is less than or equal to the the total vertices in $G_1$ and $G_2$. Then, would the union (the union of edge and vertex sets) of $G_1$ and $G_2$ have chromatic number at most one more than the maximum of the individual chromatic numbers of $G_1$ and $G_2$?

I feel this is untrue. Any easy counterexamples? Or, is the proposition true? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that $V(G_1)\cap V(G_2)=W$ where $W$ is a set of $k$ vertices which is an independent set in both $G_1$ and $G_2$? In this case it is true.

Start with any colouring of $G_1$ with colours $1,...,\chi(G_1)$, and any colouring of $G_2$ with colours $1,...,\chi(G_2)$. We use these to define the colours on $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)\setminus W$, and then colour all vertices in $W$ with the new colour $\max(\chi(G_1),\chi(G_2))+1$.

The $+1$ is necessary, e.g. if $G_1$ is an odd path and $G_2$ an even path with common endvertices.

Comment: great! but what additional conditions would still make the result true if the intersecting vertices are not independent?

Comment: also, can we use a variant of this to help us solve the Erdos-Faber-Lovasz conjecture? For example, since the graph in the erdos -faber -lovasz problem is a union of disjoint cliques sharing but one point (which is independent), therefore, we have the colors required to properly color the graph is at most one more than that required to color one clique, isnt it?

Comment: could you please post a suitable reply?